# Is there any way to set by default key focus inside init() or inside XML component

Tags: roku, brightscript

My Button is below. I tried to focusBitmapUri set in XML and also set in init(). I need to button the focus image when the application launch. So, I set this field in init(). I tried focusable = "true". But no luck.

**My XML File :**

```
<Button id="Button" iconUri="" focusedIconUri="" showFocusFootprint="true" 
focusFootprintBitmapUri="pkg:/images/button.png" minWidth="150" focusable="true" 
height="50" translation="[440,500]" />
```

**My brs File :**

```
sub init()
     m.Button = m.top.findNode("Button") 
     ?m.Button.hasFocus()
     m.Button.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/newsignin.png"
     m.Button.iconUri = ""
     m.Button.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
     m.Button.setFocus(true)
     ?m.Button.hasFocus()
     ?"m.Button.focusFootprintBitmapUri : "m.Button.focusFootprintBitmapUri
     ?"m.Button.focusBitmapUri : " m.Mac_Login.focusBitmapUri
     m.top.SetFocus(true)
end sub
```

It's Completely Working fine. After, I set this field in onkeyEvent. In Documentation said this field worked after key focus. But, **Is there any way to set by default key focus to this button when the application launches and init().**

```
function onKeyEvent(key as String, press as Boolean) as Boolean
     result = false
     if key = "OK" then
          m.Button.focusBitmapUri = "pkg:/images/Button.png"
          m.Button.iconUri = ""
          m.Button.focusedTextColor = "0x00000000"
          m.Button.setFocus(true)
          ?m.Button.hasFocus()
          ?"m.Button.focusFootprintBitmapUri : "m.Button.focusFootprintBitmapUri
          ?"m.Button.focusBitmapUri : " m.Button.focusBitmapUri
         result = true
     end if
     return result 
end function
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the focus on "OK" button press is really unusual practice. This button is used to handle the button selection event. If I am understanding it correctly, you want to set the default focus on this button. There are various ways to achieve the same. One way is to set the "***initialFocus***" attribute of "***component***" element in xml file e.g.

```
<Component id = "yourComponentName" extends = "Group" initialFocus = "Button">
.....
.....
</Component>
```